# Inner text from an element witout and element

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
<span class="start-end">
<duration>October </duration>
– December (1 duration)
</span>
```

and another one:

```
<span class="start-end">
<duration>September 2010</duration>
–
<duration>June 2014</duration>
(2 duration)
</span>
```

Generally I can use the following selector to take the result from an inner text inside and element like this:

```
document.querySelector('span.start-end duration').innerHTML
```

for `October` from the first block of code and `September 2010` for the second block.

How can I get the value from first block `December (1 duration)`
and from the second block the `June 2014` and using another command take the `(2 duration)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("start-end")
for (var k in spans) {
  var span = spans[k]
  var durations = span.getElementsByTagName("duration")
  if(durations.length == 1) {
    console.log(durations[0].innerHTML)
  } else if(durations.length == 2) {
    console.log(durations[0].innerHTML, durations[1].innerHTML)
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="start-end">
<duration>October </duration>
– December (1 duration)
</span>
and another one:

<span class="start-end">
<duration>September 2010</duration>
–
<duration>June 2014</duration>
(2 duration)
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

(2 duration) is the text of the .start-end span. I would use

```
document.querySelector(span.start-end).textContent;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to get any child element (or `:last-child` in this case):

```
document.querySelector('span.start-end duration:nth-child(2)').innerHTML
```